# what HL7 message is used to get the patient worklist for MWL

Tags: hl7

What HL7 message is used to get the patient worklist for MWL,

I need the following tag values

```
Scheduled Station AETitle
Scheduled Procedure Step Start Date
Scheduled Procedure Step Start Date Time
Scheduled Procedure Description
Scheduled Station Name
Scheduled Procedure Step Location
Scheduled Protocol Codes
Requested Procedure ID
Requested Procedure Description.
Accession Number
```

From which HL7 message and from which segment eg(OBR,ORC,) i can get the above mentioned tags.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a HL7 message related to modality worklists.
If you need to query your MWL you will need to use DICOM (http://dicom.nema.org/). You could use a DICOM library (like dcm4che: http://www.dcm4che.org/) to get your required attributes. But it is significantly more complex than HL7. But I am afraid that is your only option.

Answer (score 0):

The MSH should contain AE. The PV has scheduled time and date. Otherwise also in OBR, together with procedure id/description/codes and accession number.